# Count if account opened within 60 days of another account

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count if a member opened a product within 60 days of opening their membership with us.With the code I currently have, I'm showing no one has, which I know is not true, so I have to be doing something wrong. Any ideas?

```
SELECT M.MEMBER_NBR, COUNT(CASE WHEN S.OPEN_DATE <= DATEADD(d, -60, l.open_date) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
FROM LOAN AS L
INNER JOIN APPLICATION AS A ON L.LOAN_NOTE_NBR = A.APLNUM 
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP AS M ON L.MEMBER_NBR=M.MEMBER_NBR
INNER JOIN SHARE AS S on M.MEMBER_NBR=S.MEMBER_NBR
WHERE l.open_date = M.open_date
GROUP BY M.MEMBER_NBR
ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN S.OPEN_DATE <= DATEADD(d, -60, l.open_date) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) DESC
```

EDIT TO PROVIDE Additional data:

I'm trying to see how many members who come to us for a loan open up an additional service (checking account) within 60 days. To do this, I need to compare the Share Open Date (S.Open_date) to see if it occurred within a 60 day window of the loan open date (l.open_date).
For Example:

```
Member_NBR   Share   S.Open_Date  Loan_Nbr   L.Open_Date
1             1        6/29/2020
1                                    101      6/15/2020
```

So in the example above, they member opened up a checking account 2 weeks after signing a loan. So with the output, I'd like it to show

```
Member_Nbr   Open_ShareCount
1                   1
```

Or if they opened up a checking and a savings, it would say 2 under Open_ShareCount

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do based on that information.

Comment: `datediff(day, l.open_date, s.open_date) between 0 and 60`

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions on how the data looks and ignored both the application and membership tables for this answer. Adjust as needed.

Here's the sample data I used...
[sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcAFv.jpg)

The green highlighted rows are one's that will not appear in the results because the dates are out of bounds.

Query....

```
    select member_number, 
    count(distinct share) as accounts_opened
    from (
        select s.member_number 
        ,s.share
        --,s.open_date as share_open --kept for QA
        --,l.open_date as loan_open --kept for QA
        from share s
        join loan l on l.member_number = s.member_number
        where 1=1
        and s.open_date between l.open_date 
            and l.open_date + '1 day'::interval * 60
        )z
    group by 1
    order by 1
```